# Deserialize json into multiple classes with System.Text.Json

Tags: c#, json, deserialization, system.text.json

I have a json from a video game with around 1000 values at the root level and uses snake case keys, how can I deserialize it into multiple classes with System.Json.Text ? Thanks

For example

```
{
    "onlinepvp_kills:all": 0,
    "onlinepve_kills:all": 0
}
```

to

```
public class Online
{
    public PVP PVP { get; set; }
    public PVE PVE { get; set; }
}

public class PVP
{
    public int Kills { get; set; }
}

public class PVE
{
    public int Kills { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JSON schema doesn't directly match your class.  You might be better off creating classes designed to make deserialization easier, then use the the [Adapter Pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299167/understanding-adapter-pattern) create classes that fit your needs that consume the c# json versions.

```
public class OnlineKillsSource
{
  
  [JsonPropertyName("onlinepvp_kills:all")]
  public int PVP { get; set; }
  [JsonPropertyName("onlinepve_kills:all")]
  public int PVE { get; set; }
}
```

Then use the Adapter Pattern, with a constructor:

```
public class Online
{
    public (OnlineKillsSource source)
    {
      PVP = new PVP { Kills = source.PVP };
      PVE = new PVE { Kills = source.PVE };
    }

    public PVP PVP { get; set; }
    public PVE PVE { get; set; }
}

public class PVP
{
    public int Kills { get; set; }
}

public class PVE
{
    public int Kills { get; set; }
}
```

Usage:

```
JsonSerializer.Deserialize<OnlineKillsSource>(jsonString);

var online = new Online(OnlineKillSource);
```

Now the advantage to this that you [Separate the Concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns#:%7E:text=In%20computer%20science%2C%20separation%20of,section%20addresses%20a%20separate%20concern.&text=When%20concerns%20are%20well%2Dseparated,%2C%20reuse%2C%20and%20independent%20development) of deserializing external data and the transformation of the data into a standard consumable.

If the source of your Data changes the JSON schema, you have much less code to change to keep your code working.